# What is The POSIX standard?

Tags: linux, unix, posix

In plain and simple terms, what is the **POSIX** standard and why does it matter?
Also if I have two systems that are 100% **POSIX** compatible, would code compiled for one work on the other without a problem?

Answer (score 2):

It defines an interface (POS **I** X) to a computing environment (POSI **X**) that is meant to be portable (**P** OSIX) across operating systems (P **OS** IX). This interface extends across both user (*commands*) and program (*libraries*) space, and allows both source code as well as shell scripts to work in any given environment.

If the program only uses POSIX capabilities then it should work on any POSIX-compliant OS.

Comment: Where's the `x` in computing environment?

Comment: @Daniel: It is a little hacky, but at one point "POSIX" stood for "Portable Operating System Interface for Computing Environments".